# How do I permanently disable the spotlight key?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, hotkeys, spotlight

I'm attempting to disable my spotlight hotkey so that I can make my Alfred hotkey <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.  If I disable "Spotlight menu keyboard shortcut" through system preferences, it seems to stay disabled until I restart. After restart, the spotlight hotkey is enabled again.  How do I permanently disable the spotlight key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried disabling the shortcut and restarting, and it stayed disabled.

You could try deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`.

Or if nothing else works, you could use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to map command-space to some other key combination:

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F19</autogen>`

Comment: Deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` and then setting the key again did the trick for me. Thanks!